# Можно ли добавить "скрытый" текст который будет видно при открытии .png через блокнот?

Tags: png, jpeg

Вы наверное знаете что можно открыть картинку с помощю блокнота и увидеть не понятные символы.
Я хотел бы узнать могу ли я добавить туда какой-нибудь текст и не повредить картинку ?

Answer (score 0):

В конец файла можно дописать что угодно. Вот пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В png можно в комментарии добавить. http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.iTXt

Comment: Alexey Ten могли бы вы пожалуйста объяснить как оставлять комментарии в png просто я не смог найти в документации как это сделать .